# wrong date created with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that seems so senseless that I'm sure I'm missing something really stupid.
I have the following Javascript function that validates a date:

```
function validateDate(date){
    var re = /\b\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}\b/;
    if(!re.test(date))
        return false;

    var separator = (date.indexOf("/") != -1) ? "/" : "-";
    var aux = date.split(separator);
    var day = parseInt(aux[0]);
    var month = parseInt(aux[1]);
    var year = parseInt(aux[2]);
    alert(aux[0]+" "+aux[1]+" "+aux[2]);
    var dateTest = new Date(year,month-1,day);
    alert(dateTest); //2nd alert
    if(dateTest.getDate() != day)
        return false;
    if(dateTest.getMonth()+1!= month)
        return false;
    if(dateTest.getFullYear() != year)
        return false;

    return true;    
}
```

the first alert always shows the correct values.
if the incoming date is for example `05/07/2011`, everything works fine. The second alert shows `"Tue Jul 5 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011"` which is right.
but now, if i change the date month to august or september, the created date is wrong. for example, with date `05/08/2011`, the second alert will show `"Sun Dec 5 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2010"`.

anyone knows what could be happening??

Comment: where are you getting your date from? is it user input? is it a file? If it is user input, wouldn't it be better to use a date widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you supply a radix to `parseInt`.  If you don't, it will "guess" based on the string.  In this case, your `08` is being parsed as an octal value because of the prefixed zero and you get `0` back.

```
var day = parseInt(aux[0], 10);
var month = parseInt(aux[1], 10);
var year = parseInt(aux[2], 10);
```

Supplying a base ten number will get you the correct result.

```
//Parsing numbers:
parseInt("06");  // 6, valid octal
parseInt("07");  // 7, valid octal
parseInt("08");  // 0, invalid octal
parseInt("09");  // 0, invalid octal
parseInt("10");  // 10, parsed as decimal
parseInt("11");  // 11, parsed as decimal
parseInt("12");  // 12, parsed as decimal
```